# Pro Tools 10 OMF Export

Tags: omf, export, pro-tools-10

I can't research much on this topic as I'm in an extreme hurry to meet a deadline :

How can I export an OMF in Pro Tools 10 with my Track Names? As it stands, if you import an OMF that I exported, the track names come up as : A1, A2, A3, etc.

Mainly it's important that the mixer knows which tracks are my dedicated LFE, SFX, Foley, etc.
Is this possible?
I'm exporting from Pro Tools 10 (w/ complete production toolkit), he's importing in Nuendo.

THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick answer: I don't know if it is possible. Also, Pro Tools > Nuendo and Nuendo > ProTools transfers aren't always the smoothest. If you have that working, you're over half-way there.

Quick solution: Email. (ie. A1-A16 = SFX, A17 = LFE, A18-A22 = Foley, etc.) Never underestimate the usefulness of good 'ol communication in the face of technological "shortcomings". Especially when forced into a time-constrained corner.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Jake,

In addition to Steve's idea, try slating each track vocally. Grab any small recording device (pocket recorder, iphone, laptop mic) and record yourself reading the names of each of the tracks. Import the recording into the pro tools session and splice each recorded track name into its own region. At the end of the session (after the video file ends) put each slate recording on its corresponding track. This way you avoid any possible confusion in the transfer.

Best,
~Matt

Comment: audio slates, another great solution!